# C netbeans error

Tags: c, netbeans

I've started to learn a C language and i am using netbeans IDE.
I tried the most simple classic = printing "Hello World". 
code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf('Hello World!');
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When i run projects, netbeans writes BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: ...)
but then it writes

```
read from master failed
                       : Input/output error

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 414ms)
```

How to make it work?

Comment: `'Hello World!'` should be `"Hello World!"`

Comment: Are you including `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: ---> `printf("Hello World!");` note the double quotes for a `"string"`, single quotes are for a `'s'`ingle char. But that would have not worked with `printf` anyway since its first argument expects a `"string"` or a `"format string"`.

Comment: I am including <studio.h> and i tried it with printf("Hello World!") , but didnt work either , the error is still there

Comment: It is not `studio.h`

Comment: sorry , misspelled it.

Comment: You won't get much sympathy here with typos. If you don't post your *exact* code commenters will lose interest PDQ.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Hello World** program. It includes the relevant library header file. I added the `newline` with `\n` to ensure the output buffer is flushed.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: I included <stdio.h> whole code : #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Comment: That does not compile. `/*` starts a "comment" but `* /` (note the `space`) does not finish it. The comment should finish with `*/` (note the lack of a `space`). So basically you have commented out all the code, so it won't compile. But why put a comment in there without any text anyway? Please try my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from Netbeans IDE. Right click your project and go to properties. In the properties, click run and change the console type to standard output.